# Lambda statement syntax - help for a learner

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, lambda

This is my first post on here so please be gentle!

I am new to c# and therefore very new to lambda. I am trying to construct a lambda statement and I am getting it wrong as it is not erroring but it is not returning any value.

What I'm trying to do is select some information from a table where the database select would be

```
SELECT slope
FROM   scaleTable
WHERE  percentage = aPercentagePassedIn
```

This should just return one record.

We are using Entity Framework.

This is what I have but as I said, I know it is wrong:

```
List<ScaleTable> maxSlope = ScaleTableList.Where(a => a.Slope.Equals(ScaleTableList.Where(b => b.Percentage.Equals(aPercentagePassedIn)))).ToList();
```

Thanks for any help.

**Update 1**

Many thanks for you help @m1Lb4nKs and @Habib. I have tried all options but for some reason it doesn't like the SingleOrDefault or the Where (error is table does not contain the definition for SingleOrDefault or Where) when I'm using it with the table name as:

```
var result = ScaleTable.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Percentage == aPercentagePassedIn);
```

or

```
var result = ScaleTable.Where(x => x.Percentage = aPercentagePassedIn).Select(y => y.slope).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any ideas?

**Update 2**

Okay, thanks @Millie. I already had the using statement at the top so that's not the problem.

I changed my code to this but it errored with "Cannot implicitly convert type decimal to bool". Percentage is a decimal.

```
List<ScaleTable> maxSlope = ScaleTableList.Where(x => x.Percentage = aPercentagePassedIn).Select(y => y.slope).FirstOrDefault();
```

So I tried this but got an error that basically said it cannot convert type ScaleTable to System.Collections.Generic.List

```
List<ScaleTable> maxSlope = ScaleTableList.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Percentage == aPercentagePassedIn);
```

So, I'm still stumped and feeling "not very good at this"!!

Comment: In response to your update, put "using System.Linq;" at the top of your file. And you have to do ScaleTableList, not ScaleTable.

Comment: Percentage ==. Two equals signs. And call ToList() at the end to get rid of that error.

Comment: To explain... == compares. = assigns, so the result of the expression was a decimal. And all the linq queries return an ienumerable, not a list.

Comment: Thanks again @Millie Smith. I solved it eventually using this code which is excatly what I wanted to achieve, happy bunny :) decimal maxSlope = ScaleTableList.Where(x => x.Percentage == aPercentagePassedIn).Select(y => y.Slope).FirstOrDefault();  I should have spotted the ==, I do know the difference but thanks for pointing it out. I had been looking at this for far too long!

Comment: No problem @Isis. Btw, if you're looking for maxSlope, you're going to want to call Max instead of FirstOrDefault, right?

Comment: i.e. decimal maxSlope = ScaleTableList.Where(o => o.Percentage == aPercentagePassedIn).Max(o => o.Slope);

Comment: Hi @Millie Smith, I don't need to code specifically for the MaxSlope. I have actually passed in the MaxPercentage (as aPercentagePassedIn). The code I ended up with retrieves the Slope for the MaxPercentage, therefore by default it will be the MaxSlope, iykwim! I'm sure I probably could have retrieved the MaxPercentage and MaxSlope in one lambda statement so at some point I may go back and refactor the code. Alas I have 9 more calculations to code for in my WPF screen and time is not on my side. I really appreciate all your help and advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those visiting this question, I managed to solve it myself using the appreciated help of those who responded. The code I ended up with is:

```
decimal maxSlope = ScaleTableList.Where(x => x.Percentage == aPercentagePassedIn).Select(y => y.Slope).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
ScaleTableList.Where(x => x.percentage = aPercentagePassedIn).Select(y => y.slope).ToList()
```

If it should only return one record, then:

```
ScaleTableList.Where(x => x.percentage = aPercentagePassedIn).Select(y => y.slope).FirstOrDefault()
```